# What to do with Unicoin scams?

Tags: discussion, fun, april-fools, unicoins

I recently was approached by a trader saying they had Unicoins for sale at nearly 1/4 of the normal retail price.

How could I resist such a bargain?

I made the trade but upon delivery of said Unicoins I quickly realised I had been scammed.

What is been done to stop such scammers? and how can I avoid this is the future?

Also does anyone know what to do with 25 single-horned horses?

Comment: You should be smart and only trust real Nigerian princes (like me).

Comment: Single. Horned. Horses. Get out. Now.

Comment: @Oded Reminds me of the [geraffes are so dumb](http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/8aqjh/awww_this_is_just_too_sad_pic/c08pp5z) incident...

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Nigerian prince?. hmm. Today, I don't know what to believe on meta.

Comment: Yay! Something to vote on and... Galloping Unicorns! Worth the RSI mining all those Unicoins :)

Comment: I am so confused. What is this about? Can someone explain?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are a few things you can do to properly protect yourself against Unicoin-related scams

### Verify the Seller

Of course, you should always buy your Unicoins directly from Stack Exchange, but there will always be a market for such things from people who have already bought everything they want, so to protect yourself, you should first verify the person selling the Unicoins

Look into their reputation, both in the Stack Exchange sense, and in the general sense. Look into their history as well; a seller who has only just recently started selling, and has nothing but positive comments on their sales, is likely engaging in sockpuppetry. Their account will likely be swiftly deleted, and they are just trying to hook as many people as they can before their accounts get banned. This is especially likely to be true if their offer is time-sensitive; they are trying to get you to buy before a ban gives them away.

### Verify the coins

Unicoins have a number of anti-counterfeiting features you can use to tell the real ones from the fake:

1. Verify the material. Unicoins, being digital, should be made from a tightly-interwoven series of tubes.
2. Inspect the horn on the Unicorn; real Unicorn horns grow out of the Unicorn's head, and in an effort to glue fake horns onto their fake Unicoins' fake Unicorns, counterfeiters often leave traces of glue visible.
3. Check the date stamped on the coin; real Unicorns are only present at [certain times of year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/april-fools), and these are the only dates the coins can be mined. Time zone issues can result in some coins having a date of the day before or after, but beyond that range, the coin is likely fake.

Comment: +1 LOL, stackoverflow unicoins made my day :)

Answer (score 24):

PLease to thank you for purchasing of fine coins from shop! I gurant all purchase, and villify that they are genuine. please see the certificate included with purchase for villification!

Reminder that slander shop in public places is not nice! also may result in bad feedback for buyer. Do not do!

If you buy more please tell.

Thank you!

Best regards,
unicomania

Comment: This post uses punctuation properly, I'm not sure if I can trust it with my money.

Answer (score 3):

> Also does anyone know what to do with 25 single-horned horses?

The answer is clear: **Bacon**.

Or you use it to make Hors d'oeuvre with it, using the horn as stick as to not waste resources.

Maybe even [can it](http://www.thinkgeek.com/product/e5a7/).

Comment: Unicorned Beef...

Comment: Wait -- oh use the horn as a STick...sorry I thought you said something else....